# Running Seed Method The cast to value type <type> failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I modified an Entity to change a property from `int?` to `int` resulting in the follwing Migrations

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.ChangeLogs", "ChangeGroupId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
}

public override void Down()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.ChangeLogs", "ChangeGroupId", c => c.Int());
}
```

It looks like I can run `Update-Database`, but the Seed method seems to fail. I'm not sure which seed method EF is running, but neither my custom Initialiser class, nor the EF Code First Migrations Configuration Seed methods have any implementaion details

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'PN.Helix.Web'.
Using NuGet project 'PN.Helix.Domain'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'aspnet-PN.Helix.Web-20161223010201' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201612252335030_NullableChangeGroupIdInChangeLogs].
Applying explicit migration: 201612252335030_NullableChangeGroupIdInChangeLogs.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChangeLogs] ALTER COLUMN [ChangeGroupId] [int] NOT NULL
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201612252335030_NullableChangeGroupIdInChangeLogs', N'PN.Helix.Domain.Migrations.Configuration',  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

Running Seed method.
System.InvalidOperationException: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Max[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   at PN.Helix.Domain.DAL.HelixContext.SaveChanges() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\PacificNational\PN.Helix\PN.Helix.Domain\DAL\HelixContext.cs:line 58
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

Custom Initialiser:

```
public class HelixInitialiser : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<HelixContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(HelixContext context) { }
}
```

Migration Configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PN.Helix.Domain.DAL.HelixContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(PN.Helix.Domain.DAL.HelixContext context) { }
}
```

Most of the time when this happens on SO, it's when people are using LINQ queries. So why is this happening in an empty seed method?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it pays to review your stacktrace more carefully. I had overridden the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method which was running a `Linq` query inside it.

```
at System.Linq.Queryable.Max[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
at PN.Helix.Domain.DAL.HelixContext.SaveChanges() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\PacificNational\PN.Helix\PN.Helix.Domain\DAL\HelixContext.cs:line 58
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
```

The `Linq` query was failing due to no records in the database.